# VirtualHosts loading blank pages in Mavericks

Tags: apache, osx-mavericks, virtual-hosts

I'm having issues loading VirtualHosts I've setup on my iMac, all that they appear to be returning are blank pages. I've tried multiple browsers, flushed my DNS cache, cleared browser cache etc but nothing appears to be fixing this.

Here is what my `/etc/apache2/httpd-vhosts/conf` file looks like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/Users/chris/Sites/test/">
Allow From All
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "test.dev"
    ServerAlias "test.dev.*.*.*.*.xip.io"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/chris/Sites/test"
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is what my `/etc/hosts` file looks like:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

# VHX START
127.0.0.1 test.dev
fe80::1%lo0 test.dev
# VHX STOP
```

In my `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file I've made sure to uncomment the following line:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I'm using VirtualHostX to manage all of this but I've even resorted to deleting everything in these files and starting again following guides online – that didn't work either.

I've tried to tail the apache access log and whenever I try to access http://test.dev nothing shows up in that file or the apache error log – it's as though my machine has absolutely no idea that URL exists even though I believe everything is setup correctly.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the folder `/Users/chris/Sites/test/`?

Comment: Yea double checked permissions on the folder, I set it to `chmod 755`. All it has in the folder is an index.html file which has has "Hello World" in it. As basic as I could make it.

Comment: With the file permissions, you have to make sure the whole tree has the right access (/Users. /Users/chris etc.) but I don't think that tends to return blank pages - it gives an error instead.

Comment: Is it worth removing the double quotes in the VirtualHost config? That's the only thing I can see that I'm not used to seeing